# Can I say "let me not speak about that matter"?

Tags: letter-writing

I was writing a letter and wanted to say let's not talk about something. I wanted to know if I can say "let me not to speak about that matter". Or I need to omit the "to" because of the verb let.

Thank you.

Comment: Omit the *to* there.

Answer (score 3):

The *to* is inappropriate in

> *Let me not to speak about that matter.

Note, while  “Let me not speak about that matter” (with *to* removed) is grammatical and sensible, it is somewhat more idiomatic to say either “Let me not speak of that” or “Let us not speak of that”.  Forms like the latter occur far more frequently according to [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=me+not+speak+of%2Cus+not+speak+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) for *me not speak of,us not speak of*.